# Postgres any chance of duplicates on an insert select where not exist in a race condition

Tags: postgresql

So if I insert with the query below, is it at all possible that 2 queries both run at the same time, both see no employee with id=123 and both insert the row?

```
insert into employee (id, name)
select 123,'joe' where not exists (select 1 from employee where id=123)
```

Now I can't put constraints on this table. Or I could do a possible constraint with a where, but I'd rather avoid that as I think it could impact performance. If this can insure on a race condition that I wouldn't get 2 rows, I'd love to do this.
I'd also rather not lock up the entire table as there will be inserted and updated often.

Comment: See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530360/what-is-row-exclusive-in-postgresql-exactly) for a discussion.  I actually don't know what would happen, but my guess is that in fact one would fail.

Comment: Why isn't your ID column defined as the primary key (or at least a unique) key? An index will substantially improve the performance for looking up existing rows (the sub-query) and it will enable you to use `on conflict` instead which is much more efficient

Comment: I think I agree that the long term solution might be to have a unique key, but I can't do that yet on that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed it, there is a race condition.

- Creating a constraint = the DB server evaluates `id=123` does not exist before committing the record into the table. (1 server => no race condition)
- Using a `WHERE` ≈ each client, **independently**, checks that `id=123` does not exist before inserting the record into the table. (several clients executing concurrently, remember that clients can only see records as of right before the statement starts  => race condition)

Also, remember that in the context of transactions and depending on the isolation level, clients may have to wait a long time before seeing changes done by others.

Testing it is less complicated than you think. Try to connect 2 clients yourself, from the same computer.

**First client**:

```
create table ForceWait (val text);
with LetsWait as (
insert into ForceWait select null from pg_sleep(10)
) /*We want to make sure waiting and inserting are done in separate steps*/
insert into employee (id, name)
select 123,'joe' where not exists (select 1 from employee where id=123)
```

**Second client**, **immediately** execute:

```
insert into employee (id, name)
select 123,'jack' where not exists (select 1 from employee where id=123);
select * from Employee where id = 123
```

**Result**: the 1st query is started first but finishes last.
For a while, you will see `jack` in the table but `joe` will still get inserted. Here's your race condition.

If like you said, you keep inserting/updating in the table, then the `WHERE` clause will quickly become an equivalent from my `pg_sleep(...)` above.

---

PS: You may think the first client could have executed something a lot more simple:

```
insert into employee (id, name)
select 123,'joe' from pg_sleep(10) where not exists (select 1 from employee where id=123)
```

However, postgresql (at least version 11) is able to optimize the whole thing away if relevant (try the query, you will see it does not wait when `id=123` already exists).
This means there is a side-effect caused by the optimizer which, for testing purpose, we want to avoid.

PPS: Do not forget to drop table `ForceWait`